# Which web-resource supports OAuth 1.0 signing using PLAINTEXT (not HMAC_SHA1)?

Tags: java, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm writing (or better to say extending) one existing library to support all kinds of signature, but I would love to test it with some existing service, which uses OAuth 1.0. Currently I'm working on PLAINTEXT part. Does anybody now such kind of service, which supports Oauth 1.0 + PLAINTEXT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo! does: http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-sign-plaintext.html